# Lagom debugger Intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, lagom

I can't get the debugger to work. 
Steps to reproduce:

1) `sbt lagom:runAll`

[image]

2) `sbt -jvm-debug 5005`

[image]

3) Set remote config in Intellij + start debugging

[image]

[image]

4) Set breakpoints

[image]

5) Make request

[image]

The debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoints.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `-jvm-debug` flag on the `sbt runAll` command, like this:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005 runAll
```

The following steps in your list are correct.

When you run `sbt runAll` and `sbt -jvm-debug 5005` as separate commands, you are creating two separate sbt sessions: one that runs your services, and the other is doing nothing but waiting for input at the prompt. When you connect your debugger, it is connecting to the second, idle session, instead of the one that is running your services.

Comment: And how to do the same with maven? What to add to this command to make maven open debug port `./mvnw lagom:runAll`?

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko maybe you should open another question, but Maven ships with a script called `mvnDebug` that launches it with debug options.

Answer (score 0):

@Ruslan Stelmachenko as @Tim Moore said - just execute:

```
mvnDebug lagom:runAll
```

and maven will tell you on what port is it listening to connect with remote debug connection and will nicely wait for this connection:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but not sure what to do after it. I see message on console as 'Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000'. What to do now to hit the service in browser?

Comment: Got it. Needed to configure remote.